# Why I am unable to access base class member function with derived class object, in public inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, public

The code is :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
        void fun()
        {
            cout << "A::fun()" << endl;
        }

        void fun(int i)
        {
            cout << "A::fun(int)" << endl;
        }
};

class B:public A
{
    public:
        void fun()
        {
            cout << "B::fun()" << endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.fun(5); // throws an error.
    return 0;
}
```

In public inheritance, all the member function can be accessed with derived object. But, it is throwing me an error, when I try to access the member function of the base class. Why?